# VB Net CheckboxList Send Mail Based on ListItem Value

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, checkboxlist, listitem

I am trying to change the variable:

```
.ToAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RequestEmail")
```

based on the selected value in the CheckBoxList ListItem.  So far it's not working.

Here's the code for that list:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="m_chckbxlstProperties" RepeatDirection="horizontal" RepeatColumns="2" CssClass="checkboxlist">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
For Each li In m_chckbxlstProperties.Items
  If li.Value = "1" Then
   If li.Selected Then
    .ToAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("1RequestEmail")
   End If
  Else If li.Value = "2" Then
  If li.Selected Then
    .ToAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("2RequestEmail")
   End If
  Else If li.Value = "3" Then
  If li.Selected Then
     .ToAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("3RequestEmail")
    End If    
  Else If li.Value = "4" Then
  If li.Selected Then
     .ToAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("4RequestEmail")
    End If  
  Else
     .ToAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RequestEmail")
    End If
  End If
 Next
```

Comment: What does `.ToAddress` belong to? I'm assuming you have a `With` statement somewhere. Do `1RequestEmail`, `2RequestEmail`, `3RequestEmail`, `4RequestEmail`, `RequestEmail` exist in your web.config?

Comment: I moved your `if li.selected` to outside the value checking routine.  This code should only be executing once, so why not move it outside?  Readability improved.

Comment: Yes, the .ToAddress is in my Email.vb file in my app_code and part of the namespace Email.  You are correct, all the RequestEmails are in my web.config.  The email works fine but when the different emails for list item values were thrown in as a stick in the works it got complicated.